# Qt minimal deployment

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am looking at a Qt Windows app that hardcodes the Qt libs and files needed for deployment such as *Qt5Core.dll* and others.

Now I know there is the `windeployqt` tool to find all needed files. However it generates far more files than what is currently included. And the app seem to run fine without many of them. I am a bit unsure how windeployqt determines what is needed. Does a proper app really need **all** of those files - or does windeployqt copy more files than strictly needed ? In other words is it risky to skip some of the files it suggests ?

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit which exact files are you talking about. For example, it may be safe to leave out some particular image format plugin if you're sure that you are not using that image format. The deployment tool cannot know that.

Comment: I was not really thinking about any specific files right now, more in general how I can know *exactly* what files that windeployqt copies that are really needed. It's easy to check if the app launches or not if one file is missing of course - I am more worried about leaving out some file that might cause run-time issues in rare use cases of the app.

Comment: Make a static Qt build and make your life easy. The end result is a single executable without external dependencies. Since Qt 5.7 it can also be used for QML projects. For core + gui/widgets + network the executable is about 8 MB.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `windeployqt` at all. For use during development, you should add the necessary deployable files as targets, and add these targets to the `INSTALLS`. Then you do `[n]make install` and everything is deployed. You can add this target to Qt Creator's project configuration, so that it'll be easy to generate it.

Of course, this is still a crutch because for Windows you'll be actually wanting an installer anyway: it'll be the installer compiler's job to collect all the files necessary.

Comment: Yes, I have an installer. So I was thinking of continuing with the hardcoded file list - but retrieve them from the windeployqt output directory instead of digging around in the Qt install dir to find where they are placed originally.

Comment: It's much easier to get them from Qt directory. Their locations are all standard.